# Xcode: Iphone App version in organizer shows "local"

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode-organizer

I'm building an ipa file in xcode. I'm using the build and archive option. In info.plist file for the project, I have set "Bundle versions string, short" and "Bundle Version" to a user defined variable, which I have set in my build target's build settings to be 1.0.0.

However, in organizer, when the build and archive finishes, it shows "Version: local". Anyone know what I'm missing or if this is the correct behavior?